# What is the derivative of a complex function that includes a complex conjugate variable?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

How can I take the derivative of $f(z) = z + z^*$, where $z$ is complex, i.e. $z=a+ib$?

My question is actually for $f(z, z^*)$ in general.

My complex variables book doesn't include such an example - why not?

Comment: Conjugation isn’t differentiable.

Comment: There is a convention by which $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial}{\partial y})$, e.g. $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}z=1$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\overline{z}=0$.

Comment: For the complex derivative to be defined, the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) must be satisfied. Otherwise it doesn’t make sense to treat the variable as a single complex variable rather than two real variables. If you try the Cauchy-Riemann equations on $f(z)=z^*$ then they are not satisfied.

Comment: @quangtu123 Yes, I have encountered this convention in the context of quantum field theory, but under somewhat special circumstances that I won’t go into here.  But it’s important to note that the OP’s function is not holomorphic and therefore 99% of complex analysis does not apply, even if we use this convention for the derivative.

Comment: Perhaps an important question is why you think you need to differentiate a function dependent on $z^*$. As sasquires points out, practically all of Complex Analysis is not applicable. However, any function of a complex variable is also a function of two real variables. And Real Analysis can be applied. Depending on your need, this may be sufficient. But if you were hoping to make use of Cauchy's theorem or integral formula, or of their many implications, you are out of luck. These powerful results are true only because the functions do not depend on $z^*$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I asked, because I thought I could minimize the expression for beamformer gain just by taking the derivative, and the gain expression contains both w* and w, i.e. min(w) w*Qw.